# Pop up image without clicking anywhere

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm trying to create a pop up.

I host my own website and I would like an image to be displayed as a pop up when the website is opened.

I've tried to write some code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

       function openWin(img){

           var path = "images/"

           window.open(path+img,"mywin","menubar=0,resizable=0,width=200,height=200")
       }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="javascript:openWin('abc.jpg')">open window</a>
</body>
```

But here i dont want the `<a href>`. It shows that when I click on it the image opens but I don't want this.

I want the image to just be displayed without the need to click or hover anywhere, and I also want that when I click anywhere outside the image for it to close.

So how do I do this?

Comment: In the modern browser, no one will see the pop up because pop up blockers will block it. Thank you pop up spam ads of the 90's an 00's. What you should do is use a modal layer on top of the page so you have control over it showing and knowing when a person clicks anywhere outside of the image on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `openWin()` function in a script tag at the bottom of your html page. Don't associate it with a click or other event, just call the function. The script will run when the page loads, calling the function, which will open a new window on browsers that don't have that turned off.

Possibly, that will then annoy your users and they will go away.